# Implementing bit tricky logic in xslt 1.0 transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am finding bit difficulty to implement following logic while doing transformation using xslt 1.0.
Here is my requirement:
I need to define following logic on hours worked by an employee.
 1. anything over 8 will be OT else Regular in a day.
 2. if worked continuously for 3 days then 3rd day hours would be double time.

Here is an example:

Input:

```
<Input>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date></Date>
            <Hours></Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
            <Hours>6</Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
            <Hours>4</Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
            <Hours>4</Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
            <Hours></Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>1</EmpId>
            <Date>12/3/2012</Date>
            <Hours>3</Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>2</EmpId>
            <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
            <Hours>4</Hours>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmpId>2</EmpId>
            <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
            <Hours></Hours>
          </Record>
      </Input>
```

Output:

```
 <Output>
          <Record>
            <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
            <Detail>
              <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
              <RegHours>8</Reghours>
               <OTHours>2</OTHours>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
              <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
              <RegHours>4</Reghours>
             </Detail>
            <Detail>
              <Date>12/3/2012</Date>
              <DTHours>3</DThours>
            </Detail>
          </Record>
          <Record>
            <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
            <Detail>
              <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
              <RegHours>4</Reghours>
             </Detail>
            <Detail>
          </Record>
    </Output>
```

Would appreciate for any help.

Thanks..
Abhi

Comment: ohh sorry!!! m new to this forum didn't know the process. Have accepted the answer. Now onwards i will take care of that. Pls help me to get rid off this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRecByEmpId" match="Record[Date/node() and Hours/node()]"
          use="EmpId"/>
 <xsl:key name="kRecByEmpIdDate" match="Record[Date/node() and Hours/node()]"
          use="concat(EmpId,'+',Date)"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Record[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kRecByEmpId',EmpId)[1])]">
   <Record>
     <EmployeeId>
        <xsl:value-of select="EmpId"/>
     </EmployeeId>
     <xsl:apply-templates mode="datetime" select=
      "key('kRecByEmpId', EmpId)
               [generate-id()
               =
                generate-id(key('kRecByEmpIdDate',
                                 concat(EmpId,'+',Date)
                                 )[1]
                        )
            ]
      "/>
   </Record>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Record" mode="datetime">
    <Detail>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Date"/>
      <xsl:variable name="vTotal" select=
       "sum(key('kRecByEmpIdDate', concat(EmpId,'+',Date))/Hours)"/>
      <RegHours>
        <xsl:value-of select="8*($vTotal >= 8) + $vTotal*(not($vTotal >= 8))"/>
      </RegHours>
      <xsl:if test="$vTotal > 8">
          <OTHours>
            <xsl:value-of select="$vTotal -8"/>
          </OTHours>
      </xsl:if>
    </Detail>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Input>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date></Date>
        <Hours></Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
        <Hours>6</Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
        <Hours>4</Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
        <Hours>4</Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
        <Hours></Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Date>12/3/2012</Date>
        <Hours>3</Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>2</EmpId>
        <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
        <Hours>4</Hours>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <EmpId>2</EmpId>
        <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
        <Hours></Hours>
    </Record>
</Input>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Record>
   <EmployeeId>1</EmployeeId>
   <Detail>
      <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
      <RegHours>8</RegHours>
      <OTHours>2</OTHours>
   </Detail>
   <Detail>
      <Date>12/2/2012</Date>
      <RegHours>4</RegHours>
   </Detail>
   <Detail>
      <Date>12/3/2012</Date>
      <RegHours>3</RegHours>
   </Detail>
</Record>
<Record>
   <EmployeeId>2</EmployeeId>
   <Detail>
      <Date>12/1/2012</Date>
      <RegHours>4</RegHours>
   </Detail>
</Record>
```

Comment: I also need to implement the logic 2.if worked continuously for 3 days then 3rd day hours would be double time.

Comment: @user1905354, Please, *edit* the question and correct the provided wanted result. Right now it doesn't show the third day hours doubled. Also, it would be a good idea to split this question into two, having the second requirement as a separate question. Do note that XSLT 1.0 doesn't have standard functions for date, time and time durations. The second requirement can be easily implemented using XSLT 2.0

Comment: in the output its there for the 3rd days...pls look at the node <DTHours>3</DThours>. I can't use xslt 2.0. Pls help me i m in big trouble.

Comment: @user1905354, In an XSLT 1.0 solution you need to use a 3rd party library, such as EXSLT. I'd recommend the datetime.xsl module that comes with the XSelerator -- however it is difficult to find the XSelerator since 2-3 years -- you may be able to find an old eveluation version.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply..unfortunately i can't use any 3rd party libraray as well. One thing i m trying to implement is that..after grouping by empid and date...first i would the record sort by date string using by concancating the date in yyyymmdd format. then look for the position of date node..if it is equal to 3 then will asign the hours to the <DTHours> node.  but its not working..if anyone could help me on this.

Comment: @user1905354, Your logic is flawed. Without date arithmetic you can't determine if the third date and the preceding two dates form a date period without gaps. You may have 12/30/2012, 12/31/2012 and 01/01/2013. Or, you may have: 2/27/2012, 2/28/2012, 3/1/2012. Note that in the last case the three days are not three in a row (2012 is a leap year and the third day would have been 29th Feb.). However if you just change the year part to 2013, these three days become three in a row and *then* you have a double hours. It is very challenging to implement date-time arithmetic from scratch in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @user1905354, In case you dismiss as solution using EXSLT or an existing XSLT module, you could also consider writing an extension function in your PL that gets as parameters the string representations of three dates and returns a boolean, indicating whether or not the three dates are consecutive days.